# Detail Band overflowing to the next page and causing second list to get pushed down too much

Tags: jasper-reports

I have 2 lists in a detail band. When the first list overflows to the next page, it causes the second list to be pushed too far down, as shown in the picture of the second page of the report below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9zdU.jpg

Instead I want the lists to be closer together and not have that huge gap (I want them be about 5px apart).

I'm not sure if this has to do with the stretch type and position types of the lists or if I'm not adding the frames right.... My jrxml code for the detail band is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.5.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.5.1  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Report" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="BlankPage" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="bd180c7e-7d90-49fc-b98e-f8b9a3b499de">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.name" value="Arial"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.size" value="8"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.font.name" value="Arial"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.embedded" value="true"/>
    <subDataset name="PartyModelTabData" uuid="d55a8f11-1f95-4fe3-b165-f9c3e62742b9">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="data" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="ListOne" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <parameter name="ListTwo" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="10">
            <frame>
                <reportElement stretchType="ContainerHeight" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="10" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="69753e02-9617-4c7f-a58e-02b2d92a6ca9"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <componentElement>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="195" forecolor="#000000" uuid="132989e5-8830-41ae-bae0-064a0b031a9d"/>
                    <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                        <datasetRun subDataset="PartyModelTabData" uuid="7040fb02-57ae-4cbe-80b8-f17ac57f6e51">
                            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{ListOne}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                        <jr:listContents height="195" width="555">
                            <frame>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="45" uuid="d1c85d9e-c2e7-4c6a-a6a7-57f77b676caa"/>
                                <box>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                </box>
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="b3f699cc-8a47-4c15-b96f-8dcf67205114"/>
                                    <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Arial" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <text><![CDATA[List One]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="15" width="370" height="14" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="c79759f0-8189-468f-affc-8d465cdf96be"/>
                                    <box topPadding="3" leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <text><![CDATA[Data1]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="370" y="15" width="185" height="14" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="3398543c-a72f-45e1-a0f8-2d8bd099943b"/>
                                    <box topPadding="3" leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <text><![CDATA[Data2]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                            </frame>
                            <frame>
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="45" width="555" height="30" uuid="7588badf-6364-472e-ac95-8f9e2e333c9e"/>
                                <box>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                </box>
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="370" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="6107dc1a-fa98-4378-bfd8-8fce112bbf8a"/>
                                    <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <text><![CDATA[Data3]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="370" y="0" width="185" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="57faa09b-c9e9-48f8-bb3c-89dc957f4bd3"/>
                                    <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="4" rightPadding="5">
                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <text><![CDATA[Data4]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                            </frame>
                            <frame>
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="75" width="555" height="30" uuid="bef537d2-bc68-44c1-8728-c81d75cc0d90"/>
                                <box>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                </box>
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="370" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="ea58b0d7-4477-4622-b8c7-1b68334515f9"/>
                                    <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <text><![CDATA[Data5]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="370" y="0" width="185" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="81e6e67a-f74f-461d-94b8-95821405eed0"/>
                                    <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <text><![CDATA[Data6]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                            </frame>
                            <frame>
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="105" width="555" height="30" uuid="774d836d-10a1-403a-a731-025de0d198d1"/>
                                <box>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                </box>
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement key="" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="370" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="12f57ed8-fe6a-4e6a-8679-73153275e62c"/>
                                    <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <text><![CDATA[Data7]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="370" y="0" width="185" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="ee772a28-d050-47bf-b4e0-39c3bd62a0d3"/>
                                    <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <text><![CDATA[Data8]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                            </frame>
                            <frame>
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="135" width="555" height="30" uuid="713576f3-830e-405a-858e-190d86365e51"/>
                                <box>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                </box>
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="170" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="58a21e9b-f6fe-4d5d-9aeb-fa4ed1c4c28e"/>
                                    <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <text><![CDATA[Data9]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="170" y="0" width="200" height="15" uuid="5d9df1fa-7edd-48bb-9b2e-00e1165ee277"/>
                                    <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <text><![CDATA[Data10]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="370" y="0" width="185" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="02e8046a-e3e1-4219-8c75-d1df111f83a1"/>
                                    <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <text><![CDATA[Data11]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                            </frame>
                            <frame>
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="165" width="555" height="30" uuid="af720e0d-0853-46da-beaa-1e704fe9fea3"/>
                                <box>
                                    <pen lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                </box>
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="81b7a334-877c-4eb1-87d8-1ba6fa851874"/>
                                    <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" rightPadding="4">
                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <text><![CDATA[Data12]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="15" width="555" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="bd25126d-5218-46ba-a3c0-a01e769fb17d"/>
                                    <box leftPadding="5" bottomPadding="4" rightPadding="5">
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                                        <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{data}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </frame>
                        </jr:listContents>
                    </jr:list>
                </componentElement>
            </frame>
        </band>
        <band height="50">
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="10" uuid="eb12f699-7f9e-4f15-9c74-2fdffe8e5cf4"/>
                <componentElement>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="105" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" forecolor="#000000" uuid="ee0d2f88-9466-49d1-bac0-f2eb032e7e74"/>
                    <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                        <datasetRun subDataset="PartyModelTabData" uuid="20a0e660-38d1-4994-813f-f674989d9b96">
                            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{ListTwo}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                        <jr:listContents height="105" width="555">
                            <frame>
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="45" forecolor="#000000" uuid="72cadca6-c637-40a1-8a8d-33a40ddf1b71"/>
                                <box>
                                    <pen lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                </box>
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="16" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="dd6242b3-c7f4-4408-b50a-2bd2b6bfc4a9"/>
                                    <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" rightPadding="4">
                                        <pen lineColor="#800094"/>
                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Arial" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <text><![CDATA[ListTwo]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="16" width="555" height="14" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="71622ce3-191c-44f6-8180-ad20793ee16d"/>
                                    <box topPadding="3" leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                                        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#99059C"/>
                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <text><![CDATA[Data14]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                            </frame>
                            <frame>
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="45" width="555" height="30" forecolor="#000000" uuid="c8d03dc3-9f97-4039-abf9-6b9adb3bfe8e"/>
                                <box>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                </box>
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="370" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="9e16e960-bbad-4e85-aee0-ed6096274b9c"/>
                                    <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <text><![CDATA[Data15]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="370" y="0" width="185" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="956219c7-6008-4ae8-b369-59f1d247413c"/>
                                    <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <text><![CDATA[Data16]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                            </frame>
                            <frame>
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="75" width="555" height="30" uuid="c8aebffe-db7c-427a-9de6-b260e6c9b65d"/>
                                <box>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                </box>
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="370" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="40f726e6-4293-4c0d-b35b-89a10755a848"/>
                                    <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <text><![CDATA[Data17]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="370" y="0" width="185" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="07ae8dee-7177-4fbb-b4cf-54365e937eeb"/>
                                    <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <text><![CDATA[Data18]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                            </frame>
                        </jr:listContents>
                    </jr:list>
                </componentElement>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 0):

When jasper-reports overflows to next page it will continue to respect the height you set on the first list and the y position of your second component `y="200"`

As you have currently design the report the second list will always be at least 200 px from the top (then it can float downwards if first list is longer).

If you don't want this behavior the most common solution is to use multiple bands.

```
<detail>
   <band height="50">
      // your first list
   <band height="50">
      // your second list
   </band>
</detail>
```

In your case however, since you seem to be passing a 1 record empty datasource, I would use groups instead, this gives possibility to specify min-height remaining on page required before starting second list, hence you can avoid having just a small part of the second list on one-page and then overflowing with the rest to next page.

Comment: @PeterFriberg It still occurs when I use multiple bands. That's what I had done before and it ends up ,looking the same. I tried using sub reports (instead of lists) and it did the same thing. I will try groups.

Comment: Also the data source is getting populated in the Java code. I'm not sure how I would use groups with this,...

Comment: @sbhogal56 with 2 bands, set the height of the first band and frame to 10px (the frame will stretch) and tell me what you get. As for groups I meant that you great "dummy" groups hence a group with value expression for example "List1" (it will only be executed once)

Comment: @PeterFriberg I still get the same thing when make the band and frame 10px. The main thing is the last data value in the first list may be very big and can overflow to the next page. When that value overflows to the second page, then it causes the second list to be bumped down too much

Comment: @sbhogal56 can you past the code that you are using now

Comment: @PeterFriberg Sure. So I added the updated code to the original question which has the field 'data' in ListOne. This field expands a lot and overflows to the second page which causes ListTwo to 'float' downward too much. I also posted the link to a screenshot (https://imgur.com/a/QJHWZkQ) of what this page looks likes.

Comment: @sbhogal56 Ok yes I see, it will create the space for the component element on new page. The solution in your report is to set the height for first list of both component element and listContents to "10 px" (you need to add a frame for the list content) However I don't really like this solution because it gets very hard to edit the report visually, I would use subreport, maybe later I will delete my answer or update it explaining what I would have done.

Comment: Here is an example https://pastebin.pl/view/ce41da46, I have change the datasource some to test in preview, but it will give you an idea of what needs to be done to solve the problem in current report structure

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer but I keep getting errors saying that the report design is not valid because the elements are outside of the frame height. The elements like the test fields and static text...